# Obtain the outlier index of aq.plot() in R

Tags: r, outliers

I'm using the function aq.plot(df) in the package "mvoutlier". It nicely identified the outlier indices as an array $outliers. See the attached result. How can I obtain this array by copying the values to a new variable, like the pseudo code  `index <- aq.plot(df)$outliers`?

I have tried `index <- aq.plot(df)$outliers` and `index <- aq.plot(df)`,  both of which failed.

```
> aq.plot(df2)
$outliers
  [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [19] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [55] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [73] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [91] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[109] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[127]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[145] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[163]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[181] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[199] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[217] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[235] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

progress: The answer from Sujith DataScientist is very helpful. The indices can be obtained just by executing

```
index <- data.frame(aq.plot(df)$outliers)
which(index$outliers %in% TRUE)
```

PS: I don't understand why his answer got one vote down without any comment. It solved my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

[image]
add data.frame to it.it will create a new variable.

```
    index<-data.frame(aq.plot(train_data_1,quan=0.9,alpha=0.1)$outliers)
    table(index)
```